# How to do OR in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How can I do

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE quote_id = ".$id." AND status = 7 OR status = 8"
```

using Laravel queries.

So far what I tried doing is:

```
Test::where("quote_id", $id)->whereRaw("booking_status_id = 7 OR booking_status_id = 8")->get();
```

Comment: Test::where("quote_id", $id)->->whereIn('booking_status_id', [7,8])->get();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Test::where("quote_id", $id)
 ->where(function($query) {
 $query->where('booking_status_id',7)
 ->orWhere('booking_status_id',8);
 })
->get();
```